# Direct way to solve $y' = y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My problem is to solve the ODE $y' = y^2$.

What I would want to do is to divide by $y^2$ then integrate : it yields $y = \frac{1}{c-x}$ on an interval where $y$ does not vanish, then by continuity it is ok since there would be no way $y$ could actually vanish : it's done.

Sorry if I have been a bit unclear, but my problem is not here ; what I am asking you is :

Is there a direct way to solve this ? By direct I mean avoiding the discussion about $y$ vanishing, for example like the way $y' = y$ is classically solved (multiply by $e^{-x}$ then integrate).

(My ultimate goal is this to show that if $y' - y^2 \rightarrow_{+\infty} 0$ then $y \rightarrow_{+\infty} 0 $)

Comment: "(My ultimate goal is this to show that if $y' - y^2 \rightarrow_{+\infty} 0$ then $y \rightarrow_{+\infty} 0 $)" You might want to tell us more about this "ultimate goal", I suspect the approach in this question will not yield this result---which might actually be false.

Comment: In fact the "ultimate goal" is an exercise I have. The idea was to use the approach of $y'-y^2=0$ for $y'-y^2\rightarrow 0$. For example, if we have $y'-y=\epsilon(x)\rightarrow 0$, then multiplying by $e^{-x}$ and integrating gives $ y(x)=y(0)+e^x\int_0^x\epsilon(t)e^{-t}dt\rightarrow 0 $

Comment: Sure, except that this trick 1. does not show that $y'-y\to0$ implies $y\to0$ (try to complete the proof delineated in your comment and you are in for a surprise), and 2. does not work anyway for $y'-y^2\to0$.

Comment: 1. Yes, you're right. The example I had in mind was $y'+y \rightarrow 0$ and not $y'-y \rightarrow 0$. 2. Do you mean that the trick I used for $y'+y \rightarrow 0$ does not work for $y'-y^2 \rightarrow 0$ or that there is no trick at all for $y'-y^2 \rightarrow 0$ ? The purpose of my post is precisely to find such a trick.

Comment: Push the trick as far as you can and you will see...

Comment: Well if $y'+y = \epsilon(x) \rightarrow 0$, then $y(x)e^x-y(0) = \int_0^x{\epsilon(t)e^tdt}$ so $$y(x) = e^{-x}\left(y(0)+\int_0^x{\epsilon(t)e^tdt}\right)$$ Since $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and $\int_0^x{e^tdt} \rightarrow \infty$, we have $\int_0^x{\epsilon(t)e^tdt} = o(\int_0^x{e^tdt}) = o(e^x)$ so we're done.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to show that the trick works for $y'+y\to0$? Nobody said otherwise... What was explicitely suggested was that you push it **for the case you said interests you**, that is, $y'-y^2\to0$. (And, but on a more minor note, it was also said that the trick does not work for $y'-y\to0$.)

Comment: So I don't really understand what you're suggesting. The thing is : **a)** I know I can't just multiply by $e^x$ and integrate for $y'-y^2$ **b)** So the purpose of this post is to find another trick **c)** Currently I think Kelenner's answer might be turned into a solution for my problem : for what I tried, there are still some obstacles

Comment: Quote: "You might want to tell us more about this "ultimate goal", I suspect the approach in this question will not yield this result---which might actually be false."

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, perhaps it is what you want. Let $I$ be an interval, not reduced to a point, $y$ a (non zero) solution on $I$, and $x_0\in I$ such that $y(x_0)$ is non zero. Put $$f(x)=y(x)((x_0-x)y(x_0)+1)-y(x_0)$$We compute easily that $f^{\prime}(x)=y(x)f(x)$. Hence if $Y$ is a primitive of $y$ on $I$, there exists $d$ such that $f(x)=d\exp(Y(x))$ on $I$. But $f(x_0)=0$, hence $d=0$ and $f(x)=0$ on $I$. This show that $y(x)\not =0$ on $I$ and we finish easily.

Comment: This is not exactly what I expected, but is very nice though, and it may give the results I want in the case $y'-y^2\rightarrow 0$ ; using this method, I still have a few obstacles to overcome, but I'll see that later.

Answer (score 1):

$y(x)=0$ is also a solution of this equation, it is non linear but separable.